# CS50: Check50 isn't getting any output. Program works on my end

Tags: cs50

I'm at a lost. Check50 is saying it's receiving no output at all. I split the printf messages to try troubleshoot but still not working.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argv, string argc[])
{
    //Declares key and variables for key validation.
    //Declared charsinKey in case it ever needed changing.
    int charsinKey = 26;
    char key[charsinKey];
    bool normAlpha[charsinKey];

    if (argv != 2)
    {
        //Returns error if not exactly one argument.
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strlen(argc[1]) != charsinKey)
    {
        //Returns error if key does not contain, in this case, 26 chars.
        printf("Key must contain %d characters.\n", charsinKey);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < charsinKey; i++)
    {
        //Capitalises and stores key in key array.
        key[i] = toupper(argc[1][i]);
        if (!(key[i] >= 'A' && key[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            //Checks for invalid characters.
            printf("Invalid characters in key.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (normAlpha[key[i] - 65] == 1)
        {
            //Checks for duplicate characters.
            printf("Duplicate characters in key.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //Sets character as being in key.
            normAlpha[key[i] - 65] = 1;
        }
    }
    //Gets plaintext and sets variables required.
    string plain = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    int len = strlen(plain);
    char cipher[len];
    //Cycles through chars.
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        //Stores capital char of plaintext.
        char upper = toupper(plain[i]);
        //Checks if char is letter.
        if (upper >= 'A' && upper <= 'Z')
        {
            //Checks if char was originally capital.
            if (isupper(plain[i]))
            {
                //Stores cipher equivalent char.
                cipher[i] = key[upper - 65];
            }
            else
            {
                //Stores cipher lowercase char.
                cipher[i] = tolower(key[upper - 65]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Stores char as is, if not a letter.
            cipher[i] = plain[i];
        }
        printf("%c", cipher[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Check50 messages:

:( encrypts "A" as "Z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key

```
expected "ciphertext: Z\...", not ""
```

:( encrypts "a" as "z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key

```
expected "ciphertext: z\...", not ""
```

:( encrypts "ABC" as "NJQ" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key

```
expected "ciphertext: NJ...", not ""
```

Omitted the rest of the errors as they are the same format of expected "foo", not "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: the `normAlpha` array is not initialized. Program is giving undefined behaviour. I ran this program in the IDE and it failed *every time* on "Duplicate characters in key". Until I ran it with debug50, then it did not fail. Textbook example of undefined behaviour.

Two possible solutions to pass check50:

- declare `normAlpha` an `int` array
- initialize `normAlpha` elements in a loop.

Technically, all arrays should be initialized. I suspect the `int` array did not cause a problem locally or check50 because it reserves a bigger chunk of memory, which is "clean". Without intialization, regardless of data type, valgrind will complain about "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)". That could be a sneak preview of psets to come :)

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect. For initializing, do you need to use a for/while loop or is there anyway to shorthand it (e.g. bool normAlpha[charsinKey] = 0;)?
Also, does that mean declaring it as an int array is a bit of a hacky fix?

Comment: No and Yes :). There's no shorthand on the initialize because it is dynamically sized. If it was static , `bool normAlpha[26] = {false};` would do the trick.  I would call it a hacky fix, since it has the potential to fail in the same way.